# Is there a way to add the same object to ArrayList, but with changed values without re-writing the other elements of ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a class called CanvasState which holds two 2D arrays, and a static ArrayList.

```
public class CanvasState {

private int [][] colorArray;
private boolean [][] boolArray;
private static List<CanvasState> listState = new ArrayList<>();

public CanvasState(int [][] colorArray, boolean [][] boolArray){
    this.colorArray = colorArray;
    this.boolArray = boolArray;
}
public void addToArrayList(CanvasState canvasState){
   listState.add(canvasState);
}

}
```

So whenever the canvas is drawn on and the user lifts their finger I save the state.(This is in another Class)

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
   canvasState = new CanvasState(colors, cellChecked);
   canvasState.addToArrayList(canvasState);
}
```

I was expecting to get an ArrayList of CanvasStates holding my 2D arrays with their adjusted values, but it seems that while a new CanvasState object is being created on every ACTION_UP every CanvasObject is getting re-written so both arrays are the same for all objects in the ArrayList. Is there any way around this? OR is ArrayList not suitable for this?

Comment: Assume colors and cellChecked are different when different ACTION_UP triggered, so Why both arrays are the same?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `CanvasState` objects all reference the same 2D arrays (`colorArray` and `boolArray`).

You need to copy the current state of these arrays in your constructor.

```
public CanvasState(int [][] colorArray, boolean [][] boolArray){        
  this.colorArray = copy2D(colorArray);
  this.boolArray = copy2D(boolArray);
}
```

Using these utility methods (or some other method of your choice for cloning 2D arrays):

```
static int[][] copy2D(int[][] arr)
{
    int[][] narr = new int[arr.length][];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        narr[i] = arr[i].clone();
    return narr;
}

static boolean[][] copy2D(boolean[][] arr)
{
    boolean[][] narr = new boolean[arr.length][];
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        narr[i] = arr[i].clone();
    return narr;
}
```